# Dropbox Fails To Start With "VerificationError: importing pylinux..."

Tags: python, dropbox

Dropbox fails to start with "`VerificationError: importing pylinux...`" . It seems that some recent Python update breaks Dropbox, resulting in the following error:

```
Starting Dropbox...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dropbox/client/main.py", line 13, in 
File "autogen_explicit_imports.py", line 13, in 
File "ui/common/selective_sync.py", line 6, in 
File "arch/__init__.py", line 28, in 
File "arch/linux/tracing.py", line 8, in 
File "hard_trace.py", line 6, in 
File "client_api/connection_hub.py", line 21, in 
File "client_api/kv_connection.py", line 23, in 
File "pylinux/__init__.py", line 71, in 
File "cffi/api.py", line 311, in verify
File "dropbox/overrides.py", line 398, in load_library
File "cffi/verifier.py", line 69, in load_library
File "cffi/verifier.py", line 154, in _load_library
File "cffi/vengine_cpy.py", line 124, in load_library
VerificationError: importing '/home/maythux/pylinux/__pycache__/_cffi__xa0c4f46bx1d95b4de.so': No module named _cffi__xa0c4f46bx1d95b4de
```

Reinstalling Dropbox didn't fix this issue.

Any Idea?!

Comment: Dropbox version? And what is the OS?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcuts and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist
rm -rf ~/.dropbox-dist
dropbox start -i
```

This will remove the downloaded Dropbox binaries and re-download them. Once the download is finished, Dropbox should start normally again.

**Be careful when dealing with `rm -rf`.**

Comment: Just to be clear: `rm -rf` means `remove all the files and folders **r**ecursively and by **f**orce`. Just so you know. You could also choose to rename the files or to place them in the trash. In this case `rm -rf` is not a problem, but  inexperienced should be careful with it.

Comment: `sudo` is usually not required since this is your home folder. Avoid the use of sudo where possible.

Comment: *Sigh*. Unfortunately, for me, it just sits at "Downloading Dropbox... 100%" forever.